# How to handle many to many relationships with Angularjs' $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, many-to-many, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have two services that hold my two objects which have a many to many relationship; Missions (or steps/actions) and the Tools needed for these Missions. Each Mission can use many tools and each Tool can be used in many Missions. This seems like a straight forward and common case but for some reason I can't find anything on how to coordinate this when setting up the $scope so that I can present it in the view.

Mission Service (Mission === Step ; I changed the name half way trough)

```
  myApp.service('Missions', function(DefaultMissions, Tools){
      //set default missions stored in the DefaultMissions Service
      this.missions = DefaultMissions; 
      // to ensure unique id. if you change the preset no. of steps change this
      var newId = 9;

      //deletes a step 
      this.deleteStep = function(id){
        for (i in this.missions.missions) {
          if (this.missions.missions[i].id == id) {
            this.missions.missions.splice(i, 1);
          };      
        };
      };

      this.addStep = function(newStep){
        newStep.id = newId++;
        console.log("add step works if step is added and a new empty form is presented");
        this.missions.missions.push(newStep);
      };

      this.addTool = function(missionID, newToolId){
        for (i in this.missions.missions) {
          if (this.missions.missions[i].id == missionID) {
            this.missions.missions[i].tools.push(newToolId);
          };      
        };
      };

      //used to reset the newStep variable
      this.newEmptyStep = function(){
          return {
            id: "",
            step: "",
            time: {
              start: "",
              end: ""
            },
            place: "",
            tools: []
                };
        };
    });
```

Tools Service

```
    myApp.service('Tools', function(){
        this.tools = {tools:[]};
        // to ensure unique id
        var newId = 1;

        //deletes a mission 
        this.deleteTool = function(id){
          for (i in this.tools.tools) {
            if (this.tools.tools[i].id == id) {
              this.tools.tools.splice(i, 1);
            };      
          };
        };

        this.addTool = function(newTool){
          newTool.id = newId++;
          console.log("add tool works if tool is added and a new empty form is presented");
          this.tools.tools.push(newTool);
        };

        //used to reset the newStep variable
        this.newEmptyTool = function(){
        return {
            id : "",
            name: "",
            type: "",
            owner: ""
          };
        };
    });
```

The Controller

```
 myApp.controller('MissionCtrl', function($scope, Missions, Tools, SortService,  $localStorage){
//attributes  
  // connect the $localStorage to the $scope and set defaults
  $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default(Missions.missions);

  //sets a new empty data structure to new step
  $scope.newStep = Missions.newEmptyStep();
  $scope.newTool = Tools.newEmptyTool();

  //Events  
  //delete a step event 
  $scope.deleteStep = function(id){
    Missions.deleteStep(id);
  };

  //reset the newStep variable after it is added to the $scope.missions
  $scope.addStep = function(){
    Missions.addStep($scope.newStep);
    //sets a new empty data structure to new step
    $scope.newStep = Missions.newEmptyStep();
  };

  //delete a tool event 
  $scope.deleteTool = function(id){
    Tools.deleteTool(id);
  };

  //reset the newTool variable after it is added to the $scope.missions
  $scope.addTool = function(mission){
    //add new tool to the Tools service
    Tools.addTool($scope.newTool);
    //add new tool id to the right mission in the Mission service
    Missions.addTool(mission.id, $scope.newTool.id);
    //here I'm trying to add the new tool to the $scope
    mission.tools.push($scope.newTool);
    //sets a new empty data structure to new step
    $scope.newTool = Tools.newEmptyTool();
  };
```

I never really thought this would work because the $scope.$storage.missions hold the tool ids and not the tools themselves. But how am I meant to go about this?

I want to connect the tools to the missions in such a way that I can access each mission's tools using a ng-repeat on the missions and then a sub ng-repeat on the tools, and if I update a tool the tool should be updated in all missions that uses that tool.

Comment: $scope.mission1Tools = [{tool: 'hammer', id: 0}], probably a json like tree for tools in mission. Sorry if I misunderstood you. To find how many tools, var len = $scope.mission1Tools.length, to get the tool $scope.mission1Tools[0].tool or .id for the tool id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge objects with different values using Angularjs or Underscore js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050745/merge-objects-with-different-values-using-angularjs-or-underscore-js)