# Merge objects with different values using Angularjs or Underscore js

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I'm trying to merge two objects into a single multidimensional object for use in Angularjs controller by the 'unique_id'. (Note I also have Underscore Js added in).

Object #1 example:

```
[ 
  { "unique_id": "001", "title": "Putting Green Challenge - Motion Depends on Force and Mass" }, 
  { "unique_id": "002", "title": "Molecules to Organisms: Frog Life Cycle" }
]
```

Object #2 example (has MANY more rows than object 1..):

```
[
  {

   "ab_id": "76153F02-29F3-11D8-95EA-951BF95D9AEF",
   "unique_id": "001",
   "title": "How Speed Relates to Energy",
   "state": "NY",
   "document_title": "Core Curriculum",
   "grade_code": "K-4",
   "grade_descr": "Elementary",
   "state_id": "1.S2.3a",
   "state_text": "Use appropriate \"inquiry and process skills\" to collect data"

},
{

  "ab_id": "7980A762-29F3-11D8-BD14-861D7EA8D134",
  "unique_id": "001",
  "title": "How Speed Relates to Energy",
  "state": "NY",
  "document_title": "Core Curriculum",
  "grade_code": "5-8",
  "grade_descr": "Intermediate",
  "state_id": "1.S3.2d",
  "state_text": "formulate and defend explanations and conclusions as they relate to scientific phenomena"

}
]
```

My Controller:

```
abApp.controller("abEE", function(abService, $http, $scope, $q, _) {
  var abApp = this;

  $scope.abData = $http.get('/data/ab_activities.json', {
    cache: false
  });
  $scope.eeData = $http.get('/activities/eedata', {
    cache: false
  });

  $q.all([$scope.eeData, $scope.abData]).then(function(values) {
    var val = ??? This is where I want to merge the objects into one big multidimensional object..
});
```

Here is the output of console.dir(values);

```
0  Object { data=[28], status=200, config={...}, more...}
1  Object { data=[743], status=200, config={...}, more...}
```

This is the desired output I'd like to try and get:

```
[
  { "unique_id": "001", "title": "Putting Green Challenge - Motion Depends on Force and Mass", "alignments": [{"ab_id": "76153F02-29F3-11D8-95EA-951BF95D9AEF","unique_id": "001","title": "How Speed Relates to Energy",...}, {"ab_id": "7980A762-29F3-11D8-BD14-861D7EA8D134", "unique_id": "001", "title": "How Speed Relates to Energy",...}]
]
```

Comment: Could you please provider plunker or fiddle?

Comment: @Miraage - good suggestion!, I've really not gotten into using plunker or fiddle yet but I will try moving forward, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

after you updated the question, i created this  **<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lOFcLtrrXnd16KdWhsfE?p=preview)</kbd>**

hopes it's what you meant

[image]

---

To merge all objects by `unique_id`

```
var unions = {};

$q.all([$scope.eeData, $scope.abData]).then(function(values) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i< values.length; i++)
        {
            var value = values[i];
            
            
            if (!unions[value.unique_id])
            {
                unions[value.unique_id] = {};
            }
            
            angular.extend(unions[value.unique_id], value);
        }
    });

// Do somthing with 'unions'
...
```

Comment: I like this - keeping it all "Angular" but when I did console.log(unions); it only returns the value[1] object...

Comment: Yes they do Jossef, but there are many values in values[1] as opposed to values[0] which only has one 'unique_id' per row or record... so in database terms I guess I'm trying to do a 'one to many' relationship...

Comment: @sstrycker - i'm confused. it will be very helpful if you edit the question and provide `before` & `after` examples.

as far as i understood from your last comment, seems like you are talking about grouping values by `unique_id`..

Comment: I just added my desired output to the bottom of my question.. sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thank you Jossef, this is also close :-)  But I need to have object 1 the main object and object 2's embedded into each corresponding object 1's....

Comment: Thank you Jossef!  I was finally able to get it with your solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you could switch to use [lodash](http://lodash.com/) instead of [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), it can be achieved like this:

```
var val = _.values(_.merge(_.indexBy(values[0].data, 'unique_id'), _.indexBy(values[1].data, 'unique_id')));
```

The underscore doesn't have `_.merge()`, you have to loop through each property without it.

Comment: I've tried this and console.log(val); just returns an ["ok"] :-/

Comment: What does the `values` variable look like, try running `console.dir(values)` and include it in your question.

Comment: I've added that to my question.

Comment: I see, your data is in `.data`, I have updated the answer, please try running it again.

Comment: I think it' getting close now, I do get a return of 28 objects now but only ONE value from values[1] is being merged into each of the values[0] and I didn't want to merge I wanted to "add into" values from values[1] where unique_id matched.  I will update my answer with the desired output I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think angular or underscore have this kind of functionality. I would do something like the following pseudo-code:

```
tempObject = {}
for object in objectArray
  if tempObject[object.unique_id] isnt undefined
    tempObject[object.unique_id] = object
  else angular.extend(tempObject[object.unique_id], object) // or the other way around depending on your preference
resultingArray = []
for object, key of tempObject
  resultingArray.push(object)
```

You will have to run the `for object in objectArray` for both the returned arrays but that should work and is probably more efficient than most merge algorithms as at most it will loop through each returned arrays twice.